# Draw lines between two facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

How can I draw several lines between two facets?

I attempted this by plotting points at the min value of the top graph but they are not between the two facets. See picture below.

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
t <- seq(1:1000)
y1 <- rexp(1000)
y2 <- cumsum(y1)
z <- rep(NA, length(t))
z[100:200] <- 1

df <- data.frame(t=t, values=c(y2,y1), type=rep(c("Bytes","Changes"), each=1000))
points <- data.frame(x=c(10:200,300:350), y=min(y2), type=rep("Bytes",242))
vline.data <- data.frame(type = c("Bytes","Bytes","Changes","Changes"), vl=c(1,5,20,5))

g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=t, y=values)) +
  geom_line(colour=I("black")) +
  facet_grid(type ~ ., scales="free") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10") +
  ylab("Log values") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"))+
  geom_point(data=points, aes(x = x, y = y), colour="green")

g
```

Comment: How about using `grid.lines` from package `grid`

Comment: Add `, panel.background = element_rect(colour="black")` to your `theme`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you have to set the margins inside the plot to zero. You can do that with `expand=c(0,0)`. The changes I made to your code:

- When you use `scale_y_continuous`, you can define the axis label inside that part and you don't need a seperarate `ylab`.
- Changed `colour=I("black")` to `colour="black"` inside `geom_line`.
- Added `expand=c(0,0)` to `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous`.

The complete code:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=t, y=values)) +
  geom_line(colour="black") +
  geom_point(data=points, aes(x = x, y = y), colour="green") +
  facet_grid(type ~ ., scales="free") +
  scale_x_continuous("t", expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Log values", trans="log10", expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5), panel.margin=unit(0, "lines"))
```

which gives:
[image]

---

Adding lines can also be done with `geom_segment`. Normally the lines (segments) will appear in both facets. If you want them to appear between the two facets, you will have to restrict that in `data` parameter:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=t, y=values)) +
  geom_line(colour="black") +
  geom_segment(data=df[df$type=="Bytes",], aes(x=10, y=0, xend=200, yend=0), colour="green", size=2) +
  geom_segment(data=df[df$type=="Bytes",], aes(x=300, y=0, xend=350, yend=0), colour="green", size=1) +
  facet_grid(type ~ ., scales="free") +
  scale_x_continuous("t", expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Log values", trans="log10", expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5), panel.margin=unit(0, "lines"))
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: I used the geom_point to plot the lines I want. The lines can be non consecutive. So my question is how to add those green lines exactly in the middle of the two plots.

Comment: @Enrique See my updated answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Enrique See my updated answer, I also added another method of drawing lines.